# how can i divide a json array to 2 different json array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Hi i have a json response

```
   response.data: [{
        "id": 1,
        "datefrom": "2018-08-30 11:21:25",
        "dateto": "2018-08-31 11:21:25",
    }, {
         "id": 2,
        "datefrom": "2018-08-30 11:21:25",
        "dateto": "2018-08-31 11:21:25",
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "datefrom": "2018-09-01 11:21:25",
        "dateto": "2018-09-03 11:21:25",
    }, {
         "id": 4,
        "datefrom": "2018-09-02 11:21:25",
        "dateto": "2018-09-03 11:21:25",
    }, {
         "id": 5,
        "datefrom": "2018-09-03 11:21:25",
        "dateto": "2018-09-04 11:21:25",
    }]
```

I need to divide this json data into 2 based on the datefrom column if datefrom <"2018-08-31 11:21:25"

which should be like this:

```
json1: [{
        "id": 1,
        "datefrom": "2018-08-30 11:21:25",
        "dateto": "2018-08-31 11:21:25",
    }, {
         "id": 2,
        "datefrom": "2018-08-30 11:21:25",
        "dateto": "2018-08-31 11:21:25",
    }]
```

and

```
json2:[{
        "id": 3,
        "datefrom": "2018-09-01 11:21:25",
        "dateto": "2018-09-03 11:21:25",
    }, {
         "id": 4,
        "datefrom": "2018-09-02 11:21:25",
        "dateto": "2018-09-03 11:21:25",
    }, {
         "id": 5,
        "datefrom": "2018-09-03 11:21:25",
        "dateto": "2018-09-04 11:21:25",
    }]
```

How can i do it in javascript?

i have tried

```
if(datediff<120000){


        values.push(response.data[i]['datefrom']);
         Object.assign(values, {datefrom: response.data[i]['datefrom']});
        values.push(response.data[i]['checkout']);
         Object.assign(values, {dateto: response.data[i]['dateto']});
        console.log(values)
        $rootScope.expesscheckindata1= values;

      else{
        values1.push(response.data[i]['datefrom']);
        Object.assign(values1, {datefrom: response.data[i]['datefrom']});
        values1.push(response.data[i]['checkout']);
        Object.assign(values1, {dateto: response.data[i]['dateto']});
         console.log(values1)
        $rootScope.expesscheckindata2= values1;
```

but while doing it the data is appended as the next data like 
["2018-08-30 11:21:25", "2018-08-31 11:21:25", "2018-08-29 00:00:00", "2018-08-30 00:00:00", datefrom: "2018-08-29 00:00:00", dateto: "2018-08-30 00:00:00"]

Comment: What did you try up until now?

Comment: Please share an honest attempt at solving the problem as a [mcve] in your Question.

Comment: As a hint, if I were to do something like that, I'd look at [this function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: You have an error in your JSON twice: `" "id": 2,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the value of response.data[index].datefrom then add the value in an empty array `json1` and `json2` based on value

```js
var response = {};
response.data = [{
        "id": 1,
        "datefrom": "2018-08-30 11:21:25",
        "dateto": "2018-08-31 11:21:25",
    }, {
         "id": 2,
        "datefrom": "2018-08-30 11:21:25",
        "dateto": "2018-08-31 11:21:25",
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "datefrom": "2018-09-01 11:21:25",
        "dateto": "2018-09-03 11:21:25",
    }, {
         "id": 4,
        "datefrom": "2018-09-02 11:21:25",
        "dateto": "2018-09-03 11:21:25",
    }, {
         "id": 5,
        "datefrom": "2018-09-03 11:21:25",
        "dateto": "2018-09-04 11:21:25",
    }];
    
    var json1=[];
    var json2=[];
    
for(i=0; i<response.data.length; i++){
if(response.data[i].datefrom < '2018-08-31'){
json1.push(response.data[i]);
}else{
json2.push(response.data[i]);
}
}


console.log("JSON1: ");
console.log(json1);
console.log("JSON2: ");
console.log(json2);
```

Comment: how can i check if the datefrom is current date + 12 hours??

Comment: @BoneyJose you can use the code I provided in my answer and pass the following to the splitByDate function: `new Date(new Date().getTime()+12*60*60*1000)`

Answer (score 1):

Make yourself a method the iterates through the array and if the date is over the required date return the index

Use this index now with response.data.slice(index, response.data.length) will return array2 and and the same with slice(0, index) will return array1

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function which you want

```js
var j=[{
        "id": 1,
        "datefrom": "2018-08-30 11:21:25",
        "dateto": "2018-08-31 11:21:25",
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "datefrom": "2018-08-30 11:21:25",
        "dateto": "2018-08-31 11:21:25",
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "datefrom": "2018-09-01 11:21:25",
        "dateto": "2018-09-03 11:21:25",
    }, {
         "id": 4,
        "datefrom": "2018-09-02 11:21:25",
        "dateto": "2018-09-03 11:21:25",
    }, {
         "id": 5,
        "datefrom": "2018-09-03 11:21:25",
        "dateto": "2018-09-04 11:21:25",
    }]


var a1=[],a2=[]
function splitingByDate(_date){
  j.map(function(a){
    (new Date(a.datefrom)<new Date(_date))?a1.push(a):a2.push(a)
  })
}
//calling the function

splitingByDate("2018-08-31 11:21:25")

//Printing the Output
console.log(a1)
console.log("-------------------------")
console.log(a2)
```

Comment: If you mutate you should use `j.forEach` probably better to not define a1 and a2 but use reduce `return j.reduce((result,item)=>{(item<_date)?result[0].push(item):result[1].push(item);return result;},[[],[]])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter:

```js
data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        datefrom: '2018-08-30 11:21:25',
        dateto: '2018-08-31 11:21:25',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        datefrom: '2018-08-30 11:21:25',
        dateto: '2018-08-31 11:21:25',
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        datefrom: '2018-09-01 11:21:25',
        dateto: '2018-09-03 11:21:25',
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        datefrom: '2018-09-02 11:21:25',
        dateto: '2018-09-03 11:21:25',
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        datefrom: '2018-09-03 11:21:25',
        dateto: '2018-09-04 11:21:25',
    },
];

console.log(
    "smaller",
    data.filter(
        item=>
            item.datefrom.localeCompare("2018-08-31 11:21:25")===-1
    )
);
console.log(
    "bigger",
    data.filter(
        item=>
            item.datefrom.localeCompare("2018-08-31 11:21:25")!==-1
    )
);

const splitByDate = (date,array) =>
  array.reduce(
    (result,item)=>{
      (new Date(item.datefrom).getTime())<date.getTime()
        ? result[0].push(item)
        : result[1].push(item);
      return result;
    },
    [[],[]]//initial result
  );
const [low,high] = splitByDate(new Date('2018-08-31 11:21:25'),data)
//12 hours from now:
//const [low,high] = splitByDate(
//    new Date(new Date().getTime()+12*60*60*1000)
//    ,data
//);
console.log(
  "date compare low",
  low,
  "date compare high",
  high
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        datefrom: '2018-08-30 11:21:25',
        dateto: '2018-08-31 11:21:25',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        datefrom: '2018-08-30 11:21:25',
        dateto: '2018-08-31 11:21:25',
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        datefrom: '2018-09-01 11:21:25',
        dateto: '2018-09-03 11:21:25',
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        datefrom: '2018-09-02 11:21:25',
        dateto: '2018-09-03 11:21:25',
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        datefrom: '2018-09-03 11:21:25',
        dateto: '2018-09-04 11:21:25',
    },
];
var json1 = [];
var json2 = [];
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
    if (value.datefrom == '2018-08-31 11:21:25') {
        json1.push(value);
    } else {
        json2.push(value);
    }
});
console.log("one",json1);
console.log("two",json2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `var json1 = []` would be simpler. No jQuery needed, you cn use response.data.forEach((value,index)=>...` I think the compare should be smaller than, you could use `localeCompare` for strings and something with date if relative to now.

Comment: You should test your code before posting:
- `json1.datefrom` should be `value.datefrom`
- it should be `>` (or `<`) instead of `==`

Also, why the `eval`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method of array and [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) to check the date value from current date to get the required result.

**DEMO**

```js
const data=[{"id":1,"datefrom":"2018-08-30 11:21:25","dateto":"2018-08-31 11:21:25"},{"id":2,"datefrom":"2018-08-30 11:21:25","dateto":"2018-08-31 11:21:25"},{"id":3,"datefrom":"2018-09-01 11:21:25","dateto":"2018-09-03 11:21:25"},{"id":4,"datefrom":"2018-09-02 11:21:25","dateto":"2018-09-03 11:21:25"},{"id":5,"datefrom":"2018-09-03 11:21:25","dateto":"2018-09-04 11:21:25"}];

let result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
    let index = Date.parse(o.datefrom) < Date.now() ? 0 : 1;
    r[index].push(o);
    return r;
}, [ [],[] ]);

console.log(result[0],'\n\n',result[1])
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to parse the JSON to make it a javascript object.

It is done with the built-in javascript class JSON:

`var jsObj = JSON.parse(json);`

Since the root of your json is a json array jsObj will be a javascript Array.

Javascript built-in arrays have utilitary methods for manipulating and traversing them.

[Javascript Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array)

By reading the docs you will learn about `Array.prototype.findIndex` and `Array.prototype.slice`

`Array.prototype.findIndex` takes a predicate as argument, that is a function that will be executed for each element in the array and should return true when the element you seek is encoutered:

```
var refTime = new Date('2018-08-31 11:21:25').getTime();
var index = jsObj.findIndex(function(elem) {
    var currentTime = new Date(elem.datefrom).getTime();
    // will return true when encoutering the first occurence of a date > refDate
    return currentTime > refTime;

});
let result = jsObj;
// if the index returned by findIndex is equal to -1 it means that no element satisfying the predicate were found so result will be the original array (jsObj)
if (index !== -1) {
    // we have found an index around which we want to divide the array so result will be an array containing the two resulting arrays
    result = [jsObj.slice(0, index), jsObj.slice(index)];
}
```

Note that this code expects the element in the arrays to be sorted by datefrom in ascending order. If it's not the case then you also need to sort the array in ascending order first, which is done this way:

```
jsObj.sort((e1, e2) => {
    var time1 = new Date(e1.datefrom).getTime();
    var time2 = new Date(e2.datefrom).getTime();
    return Math.sign(time1 - time2);
});
```

I'm sure other people have pointed you how to iterate the array and populate the resulting arrays by pushing into them depending on your condition, but this answer is a pure response to how to 'divide an array' by standard array manipulation tools.

[Working fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/zfys7m6t/5/) (inspect the console to see the result)

Look into [Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/slice), [Array.prototype.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/findIndex) and [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/sort)